# Why is CrystalReports skipping records within Groups?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a simple CrystalReports defigned.
Screen Shot:

[image]

I Fill the DataSet in the Form Load

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalReport2 report = new CrystalReport2();

        DataSet data = GetData();

        report.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle = "My Company Billing Report";

        report.SetDataSource(data);

        DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1);

        Debug.WriteLine("Start Time: " + startTime);

        DateTime endTime = startTime.AddMonths(1);

        Debug.WriteLine("End Time: " + endTime);

        report.SetParameterValue("StartTime", startTime);
        report.SetParameterValue("EndTime", endTime);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

        //crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private static DataSet GetData()
    {
        string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeSheetContext"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection {ConnectionString = connectString};

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            Connection = connection,
            CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblTimeWorked ORDER BY Link2Customer, Link2Worker, DateWorked, Location"
        };

        BillingDataSet ds = new BillingDataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        int blah = da.Fill(dataSet: ds, srcTable: "tblTimeWorked");
        Debug.WriteLine("# of TimeWorked Records: " + blah);

        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblActivity";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        blah = da.Fill(dataSet: ds, srcTable: "tblActivity");
        Debug.WriteLine("# of Activity Records: " + blah);

        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomer";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        blah = da.Fill(dataSet: ds, srcTable: "tblCustomer");
        Debug.WriteLine("# of Customer Records: " + blah);

        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblWorker";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        blah = da.Fill(dataSet: ds, srcTable: "tblWorker");
        Debug.WriteLine("# of Worker Records: " + blah);

        return ds;
    }
```

The format is what I wanted, but it seems to be missing a few entries. It Looks to me like only the First Person (Worker) is ever selected and none of the others. I am Grouping By Customer then By Employee in CrystalReports. I do not do any filtering filling the dataset. I verified the records are there with Sql Server Management Studio.

Record selection is:

```
    {tblTimeWorked.DateWorked}  >= {?StartTime} and {tblTimeWorked.EndTime}  < {?EndTime} and {tblTimeWorked.Link2Activity} = 2
```

Why is CrystalReports skipping records within Groups?

Comment: try check the records from database when same filtering is applied... if the data retrived is only first person and need to modify the filtering criteria becuase if dataset is returing only first person then you can't expect crystal report to return full data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd try is to remove the Group1 and Group2 from the Crystal Report, and run the report, just to confirm that the crystal report does contain all of the detail rows you would expect. Also (and perhaps more importantly), it seems weird to be including the multiple datasets in the report. Just modify your first CommandText to include the joins needed to pull the other linked fields you need (e.g. Customer Name, Employee Name). That will simplify things.